# How to get dropped area id on drop event jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsf-2

i need the id of my area droppable thats inside a p:datatable .
i can get the text of the element dropped but not the id of area droppable
i think its something like ui.xxxx
that is my jquery code :

```
 $( init );
            function init() {

            $(".list-items").sortable({
            connectWith: '.list-items',
            items: "li:not(.item.new)",
            placeholder: 'place-holder',
            scroll: false,
            tolerance: "pointer",

                receive : function(e, ui) {

                //alert(ui.item.text());

                    if(ui.item.text()=="51173115") {

                         //$("#myDialog").dialog(dialogOpts);
                         //$(".item").dialog(dialogOpts);

                  jConfirm('item capacite Cuisson epuise vous voulez continue comme meme ?', 'alerte', function(r) {     
                  if(r)   
                  {

                   }
                    else
                    {
                    $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel'); // refuse element to be dropped
                    }
                     });

                    // comfirm dialogue
                    //var answer = confirm("capacite Cuisson epuise vous voulez continue comme meme ?");

                    //if (answer){

                    //}
                    //else{
                        //$(ui.sender).sortable('cancel'); // refuse element to be dropped

                    //}




                    }
                }

        }).disableSelection();

        }
```

how i can get the id of the zone dropped with at think like ui.xxx ??

Comment: i found $(ui.item).parent().children().index(ui.item) that return the order of item where he is dropped (first position second position ...) but i still need to know how to get the id the droped area

Comment: What is the HTML you are using? Use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) to provide a code sample of what you have. But I think you want http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive since you are using connected elements

Comment: i used ui.originalPosition but i got this  [object Object]

Comment: as i showed i can get easly the name of the object dropped with ui.item.text() i think there is something like it to show the id of dropped area and the original area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little tricky to see exactly what you are trying to achieve without some HTML and sample, I think you are tackling this from the wrong angle. You can to check when the the item is received, not when the item is dropped, if that makes sense, so you need to trigger the [sortable receive](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) event.

Try this [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qj4GG/).

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    $( ".connectedSortable" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      receive: function( event, ui ) {
          console.log('drop area id: ' + this.id);
      }  
    }).disableSelection();
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.connectedSortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 2.5em; float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
.connectedSortable li { margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; width: 120px; }
```

Comment: and when i use ui.item.attr('id') i get undefined

Comment: did you check the dev tools console window? can you share a jsFiddle of your work with the HTML markup.

Comment: i got with this the parent id because in my case i have a column :                 <p:column headerText ="les of" style="width:550px;"> 
                       <ul id="uldroite" class="list-items ui-sortable">  
                        <ui:repeat value="#{op.orderedOf}" var="vari" >  
                            <li class="item"  ><a  title="#{vari}">#{vari}</a></li>
                        </ui:repeat>                        
                        </ul> 
                </p:column>

Comment: you reponse of my question in this post is true. can you see my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787598/why-ui-item-attrid-return-indefined-value