# why ui.item.attr("id") return undefined value?

Tags: jquery, jsf

I am working with sortable between `<li>` of `<ul>` but when I try to get `ui.item.attr("id")` I got undefined but other variable are working well like `$(this).attr('id')` and `'+ui.sender.attr('id')` but I am searching the index of the `<ul>` where the element dragged from.

my js file :

```
 $( init );
      function init() {

            $(".list-items").sortable({
                 connectWith: '.list-items',
                 items: "li:not(.item.new)",
                 placeholder: 'place-holder',
                 scroll: false,
                 tolerance: "pointer",update: function (event, ui) {
                 //alert($(this));
            }, 
            receive : function(e, ui) { 
                 alert('zone : '+ ui.item.attr("id"));            

                 alert('Where the item is dropped : '+$(this).attr('id')); // Where the item is dropped
                 alert('from where the item is dragged : '+ui.sender.attr('id')); // from where the item is dragged

                 if(ui.item.text()=="51173115") {

                      jConfirm('item '+ui.item.context.id+' capacite Cuisson epuise vous voulez continue comme meme ?', 'alerte', function(r) {     
                  if(r)           
                  {

                  }
                  else
                  {
                       $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel'); // refuse element to be dropped
                  }
           }
      }

 }).disableSelection();

        }
```

my jsf code :

```
<div class="gauchedragdrop"> 

        <p class="ui-widget-header" style="margin:0;padding:5px;color: #2779bb;">tableof</p>
          <ul id="ulgauche" class="list-items ui-sortable " > 
            <ui:repeat value="#{gestionduplanning.listzp01Equipe}" var="vari" >
                    <li class="item"><a  title="#{vari.ordre.toString()}">#{vari.ordre.toString()}</a></li>
            </ui:repeat>            
          </ul>    
</div> 
<div class="droitedragdrop">

            <p:dataTable var="op" value="#{ gestionduplanning.EQlistoneequipe.get(0).listop}" style="width: 700px;float: left;">

                <p:column headerText ="les of" style="width:550px;"> 
                       <ul id="uldroite" class="list-items ui-sortable">  
                        <ui:repeat value="#{op.orderedOf}" var="vari" >  
                            <li class="item"  ><a  title="#{vari}">#{vari}</a></li>
                        </ui:repeat>                        
                        </ul> 
                </p:column>
               </p:dataTable>

        </div>
```

why i get undefined value and how can I get this value ?

Comment: could you not use `ui.item.context.id` as in your code above?

Comment: i got nothing with this my problem i got always the id= uldroite but i need for each ul created in the table get the index of this <UL>

Comment: when ul created dynamicly and have same id whats gonna be the difference between each UL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `ui.item` is a collection of objects, so you need to use `ui.item.context.id` to get the id of the item that is the dragged element, as specified in the [jQuery Sortable documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive):

> ui.item
>
> Type: jQuery
>
> The jQuery object representing the current dragged element

So your case `ui.item` will be the `<li>` that are dragged and since they do not have an id attribute set on them `ui.item.context.id` will always be empty.

If you set an id on `li` then you can access it: http://jsfiddle.net/qj4GG/2/

What property exactly are you trying to get? What do you need it for?

Comment: This is now out of date. Use `ui.item.attr('id')` to get the ID.

Answer (score 1):

You may try
`ui.item.option.childNodes[0].parentNode.parentNode.attributes[2].value`

Just change attributes[] index value to as per order of id. Here I have two attributes before id.

```
this._on( this.input, {
      autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.item.option.selected = true;
        alert(ui.item.option.childNodes[0].parentNode.parentNode.attributes[2].value);
        this._trigger( "select", event, {
          item: ui.item.option
        });
      },
```